# Python implementation of optimization coverage type of problem

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I was wondering if I can frame my optimization problem using scipy.optimize, or a different Python package.
This is the problem.
I've got two matrices of 0's and 1's.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
event1 = random.choice([0, 1], size=(20,10), p=[9./10, 1./10])
event2 = random.choice([0, 1], size=(20,10), p=[5./10, 5./10])
```

I want to find an optimal subset of rows (if I choose row x for matrix event1 then I have to choose row x also for matrix event2), so that:

`sum(event2[rows_select].sum(axis=0) > 0)` is minimum

subject to

```
mean(event1[rows_select].sum(axis=0) > 0) >= p --where 0<p<1
```

where in this example row_Select is random, but that is actually what needs to be optimized.

```
rows_select = random.choice([False, True], size=(20,), p=[5./10, 5./10])
```

Comment: This looks NP-hard. `scipy.optimize` is focused on continuous optimization, not the kind of discrete optimization you'd have to do for this problem. I think you could probably transform this to some kind of SAT or set cover problem or something and feed it to an appropriate solver.

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: The matrices are approximately 100 x 100k